# Checking for null,empty variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I always endup doing this to cover all situations where `@variable` can be empty or null,

```
 IF(COALESCE(@variable,'') <> '')
    BEGIN


    END
```

Is this the most optimal way to check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a variable, then it shouldn't matter. If you are doing a similar filter on a column of a table, then I would recommend:
`WHERE Column IS NOT NULL OR Column <> ''` as it mantains the use of a possible index on that column.

Comment: what you mean by it does not matter on a variable?

Comment: He means there is no performance impact for variables, when compared to separating the IS NULL test from the <> '' test, because variables aren't indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @variable is a VARCHAR/NVARCHAR then the following should do the same job:

```
IF @variable > ''
    BEGIN
    ...    
    END
```